Not able to access the PDF element inside the embed in Selenium C#
Below is the HTML structure from my website
<div>
<iframe src="link.pdf" width="100%" height="500"> 
#document <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(82, 86, 89);"><embed name="123333" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="1234"></body></html> 
</iframe>
</div>

Attach link for the new DOM structure after inspecting download from PDF viewer
Embedded PDF Viewer reference
<body>
<pdf-viewer id="viewer"></pdf-viewer>
> #shadow-root(open)
<viewer-toolbar id="toolbar">
> #shadow-root(open)
<div id="toolbar">
  <div id="start">
    <cr-icon-button id="sidenavToggle" title="Menu" aria-label="Menu" iron-icon="cr20:menu" aria-expanded="true" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
    </cr-icon-button>
    <span id="title"><!--?lit$02748104126$-->D5F1C5BE75754D2065258671002817C2_GAQC_Alert_No._421.pdf</span>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <viewer-page-selector style="--page-length-digits: 1;">
    </viewer-page-selector>
    <span class="vertical-separator"></span>
    <span id="zoom-controls">
      <cr-icon-button title="Zoom out" aria-label="Zoom out" iron-icon="pdf:remove" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
      </cr-icon-button>
      <input type="text" value="100%" aria-label="Zoom level">
      
      <cr-icon-button title="Zoom in" aria-label="Zoom in" iron-icon="pdf:add" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
      </cr-icon-button>
    </span>
    <span class="vertical-separator"></span>
    <cr-icon-button id="fit" title="Fit to page" aria-label="Fit to page" iron-icon="pdf:fit-to-height" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
    </cr-icon-button>
    <cr-icon-button id="rotate" suppress-rtl-flip="" aria-label="Rotate counterclockwise" title="Rotate counterclockwise" iron-icon="pdf:rotate-left" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
    </cr-icon-button>

    <!--?lit$02748104126$-->

  </div>
  <div id="end">
  
    <viewer-download-controls id="downloads">
    </viewer-download-controls>
    <cr-icon-button id="print" title="Print" aria-label="Print" iron-icon="cr:print" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
    </cr-icon-button>
    <cr-icon-button id="more" title="More actions" aria-label="More actions" iron-icon="cr:more-vert" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false"></cr-icon-button>
  </div>
</div>
</viewer-toolbar>


</body>

While accessing Embed as below getting an exception
 frameElement = WebElementFinder.GetElement(Driver, XPATHOFFrame);
     Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameElement);
    
     IWebElement elementInsideIframe = Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("embed"));
     IWebElement shadowHost1 = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("viewer"));
     ISearchContext shadowRoot1 = shadowHost1.GetShadowRoot();
     IWebElement shadowHost2 = shadowRoot1.FindElement(By.Id("toolbar"));
     ISearchContext shadowRoot2 = shadowHost2.GetShadowRoot();
     IWebElement shadowHost3 = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("downloads"));
     ISearchContext shadowRoot3 = shadowHost3.GetShadowRoot();
     IWebElement shadowHost4 = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("download"));
     ISearchContext shadowRoot4 = shadowHost3.GetShadowRoot();
     shadowRoot4.FindElement(By.Id("icon")).Click();

Exception :"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#viewer"

Please [edit] your question to include the HTML rather than posting a screenshot.

@GregBurghardt , Added HTML

@KJ , First DOM is from the application which includes embed tag that contains the PDF viewer embed to it and second HTML is the DOM for the PDF .
I want to access the download button (or any element) from the PDF viewer . I have updated the question with a new link of how the PDF viewer display in my application. Link : Embedded PDF Viewer reference

I suspect the exception occurs because you're trying to search the entire document for "#viewer" after switching to the iframe, but the viewer element is actually inside shadow DOM trees that need to be traversed hierarchically. Maybe you can try to find pdf-viewer first, access its shadow root and then search within each shadow root context for child elements.

Selenium can only access the DOM.  It can't access an embedded viewer.  (If you want to download the file you might try doing that in your native code.  Seems like this is a static file.  get the SRC of the iframe... should be full URL to static file.)

there are also some options you can use to turn off the embedded viewer and force a download.  Something like "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally" for Chrome?
